# Update DataTable content with ajax

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I am working with DataTables with AJAX where I generate a table when the page loads. This first part of my code works fine. Then I have a dropdown which filtering users in DataTable. I can choose usersname and send POST request to controller and it generates json data. But I can't find a way how to send this json data back and update DataTable. Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult IndividualUser()
{            
    var taskAnswer = new List<TaskAnswerView>();
    return View(taskAnswer);
}

public ActionResult IndividualUserGetData(string id)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var applicationUser = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == id);
    if (applicationUser != null)
    {
        var userId = applicationUser.Id;
        var user = db.Users.Find(userId);
        var list = db.TasksModels
            .Join(db.TaskToUsers, t => t.TasksModelID, usr => usr.TasksModelID, (t, usr) => new { t, usr })
            .Where(t1 => t1.usr.UserIdInt == user.ApplicationUserId)
            .Select(t1 => new
            {
                t1.t.Heading,
                t1.t.TasksModelID,
                t1.t.EndDate,
                t1.t.StartDate,
                t1.t.Content,
                t1.t.CreatedBy,
                t1.t.CreatedOn,
                Status = t1.t.EndDate > now && t1.t.StartDate < now ? "Open" : "Closed",

                ttu = t1.t.TaskToUsers.Select(t => new
                {
                    reply = t.ReplyToTasks.Where(x => x.TaskToUser.UserIdInt == user.ApplicationUserId).Select(r => new
                    {
                        answer = r.UserAnswer,
                        answerTime = r.AnswerTime,
                    }),
                    user = db.Users.Where(f => f.ApplicationUserId == user.ApplicationUserId).Select(u => new
                    {
                        fullName = u.Name + " " + u.Surname
                    })
                })
            }).ToList();
        return Json(new { data = list }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        var data = db.TasksModels.Select(s => new
        {
            s.Heading,
            s.StartDate,
            s.EndDate,
            s.CreatedBy,
            s.CreatedOn,
            Status = s.EndDate > now && s.StartDate < now ? "Open" : "Closed",

            ttu = s.TaskToUsers.Select(t => new
            {
                reply = t.ReplyToTasks.Select(r => new
                {
                    answer = r.UserAnswer,
                    answerTime = r.AnswerTime,
                }),
                user = db.Users.Where(f => f.ApplicationUserId == t.UserIdInt).Select(u => new
                {
                    fullName = u.Name + " " + u.Surname
                })
            })
        }).ToList();

        return Json(new { data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }            
}
```

---

```
@model IEnumerable<DeadLiner.Models.TaskAnswerView>
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Individual User";

   var options = new AjaxOptions()
    {        
      Url = Url.Action("IndividualUserGetData"),
      LoadingElementId = "loadingIndicator",        
    };
  }
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(options))
{
  <div class="tablecontainer">
    <p>
        @Html.DropDownList("id", new SelectList(new[] { "Ragim-A", "qurban" 
         }, "Murad"))
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
    <div id="loadingIndicator" style="display:none;">Loading...</div>
    <table class="table table-bordered ui" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Details
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Heading)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StartDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EndDate)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedBy)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CreatedOn)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
}

@section scripts
{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD/MM/YYYY');
        $.fn.dataTable.moment('dddd, DD/MM/YYYY');

        var oTable = $("#myTable").DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/TasksModels/IndividualUserGetData",
                "type": "get",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columnDefs": [
                { "className": "dt-center", "targets": 6 }
            ],
            "order": [[3]],
            "columns": [
                {
                    "class": "details-control",
                    "orderable": false,
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": ""
                },
                { "data": "Heading", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "data": "StartDate",
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        if (type === 'display' || type === 'filter') {
                            var rowvalueallday = row["EndDate"];
                            if (rowvalueallday == 0) {
                                return (moment(data).format("ddd DD/MM/YYYY"));
                            } else {
                                return (moment(data).format("MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm"));
                            }
                        }
                        return data;
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "EndDate",
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        if (type === 'display' || type === 'filter') {
                            var rowvalueallday = row["EndDate"];
                            if (rowvalueallday == 0) {
                                return (moment(data).format("ddd DD/MM/YYYY"));
                            } else {
                                return (moment(data).format("MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm"));
                            }
                        }
                        return data;
                    }
                },
                { "data": "CreatedBy", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                    "data": "CreatedOn",
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "render": function (data, type, row) {
                        if (type === 'display' || type === 'filter') {
                            var rowvalueallday = row["EndDate"];
                            if (rowvalueallday == 0) {
                                return (moment(data).format("ddd DD/MM/YYYY"));
                            } else {
                                return (moment(data).format("MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm"));
                            }
                        }
                        return data;
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data": "Status",
                    "autoWidth": true,
                    "render": function (data) {
                        if (data == "Open") {
                            return '<i class="fa fa-unlock bat" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green;"></i>';
                        }
                        return '<i class="fa fa-lock bat" aria-hidden="true" style="color:red;"></i>';
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a js function in which put your datatable code and it's parameter are the filter value that you want to apply on datatable. Initially these filter values are `null` or `blank`, when these filters are applied they have some values in it. Post these filters value along with the datatable call to these server. Call this function on page load, as well as on filters applied.

On the server check if these filters are not null, then apply them with in the query, otherwise skip them. By this way, your function will handle each and every possibilities on its own.

Comment: I think i cant understand your well. Can you write code of your explanation please?